# elements of oriented matroids belonging either to positive circuits or positive cocircuits

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, matroids

I need to prove the following, which seems trivial because it follows from the Farkas lemma (you may know this as the 3 or 4 painting lemma). Can someone show me how to prove this, please? I'm a bit frustrated. Thank you.

[image]